# awk | Add new row or update existing row in a file

Tags: awk

I want to update **file1** on the basis of **file2**. If any row is new in file2 then it should be added in file1. If any row from file2 is already in file1, then update that row with the row from file2 if the time is greater in file2.

file1

```
DL,1111111100,201312051013,val,FIX01,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111101,201312051014,val,FIX01,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111102,201312051015,val,FIX01,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111103,201312051016,val,FIX01,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2
```

file2

```
DL,1111111101,201312041013,val,FIX02,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111102,201312051016,val,FIX02,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111102,201312051017,val,FIX02,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111104,201312051014,val,FIX01,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111104,201312051016,val,FIX02,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2
```

newfile1

```
DL,1111111100,201312051013,val,FIX01,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111101,201312051014,val,FIX01,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111102,201312051017,val,FIX02,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111103,201312051016,val,FIX01,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2  
DL,1111111104,201312051016,val,FIX02,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2
```

Notes:

- 2nd field should be unique in the output.
- Addition of new value: the latest 2nd field for value "1111111104" in `file2` is taken which is newer (201312051016) then old value (201312051014) on the basis of date column (3rd field).
- Update an existing value: updated "1111111102" with newer value on the basis of date in 3rd column
- file1 is very LARGE whereas file2 has 5-10 entries only.
- row with 2nd field "1111111101" doesn't need to b updated because it's entry in `file1` already has the latest date "201312051014" as compared to new date "201312041013" in `file2`.

I haven't tried much on this because it really has complex condition for me as beginner..

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }  
FNR == NR {  
  m=$2;  
  a[m] = $0;  
  next  
}  
{  
  if($2 in a)  
  {  
        split(a[$2],datetime,",")  
        if($3>datetime[3])  
                print $0;  
        else  
                print a[$2]"Old time"  
  }  
  else print $0"NOMATCH";  
  delete a[$2];  
}
```

Comment: What is the question? I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Try explaining what you want rather than just posting some files and unintelligible notes - then someone will help.

Comment: I apology on that if I am not able to explain it properly.. Now I have added the small summary as well.. Let me know if I need to explain mote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `file1` is very large but `file2` is very small (5-10 entries), you need to read all of `file2` into memory first, dealing with the duplicate values.  As a result, you'll have an array indexed by the record number with the new data; you should also have a record of the date for each record in a separate array.  Then, as you read the main file, you look up the the record number and the date in the arrays, and if you need to, substitute the saved new record for the incoming old record.

Your outline script is most of the way there. It is more complex because you didn't save the dates coming in.  This more or less works:

```
awk -F, '
FNR == NR { if (!($2 in date) || date[$2] < $3) { date[$2] = $3; line[$2] = $0; } next; }
          { if ($2 in date)
            {
                if (date[$2] > $3)
                    print line[$2]
                else
                    print
                delete line[$2]
                delete date[$2]
            }
            else
              print
          }
END       { for (l in line) print line[l]; }' file2 file1
```

Sample output for given data:

```
DL,1111111100,201312051013,val,FIX01,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2
DL,1111111101,201312051014,val,FIX01,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2
DL,1111111102,201312051017,val,FIX02,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2
DL,1111111103,201312051016,val,FIX01,OptIn,N,Ext1,Ext2
DL,1111111104,201312051016,val,FIX02,OptIn,Y,Ext1,Ext2
```

However, if there were 4 new records, there's no guarantee that they'd be in sorted order, though they would all be at the end of the list.  It would be possible to upgrade the script to print the new records at the appropriate place in the list *if* the input is guaranteed to be in sorted order. You simply have to search through the list of lines to see whether there are any lines that should be printed before the current line, and if so, do so (and delete the record so that they are not printed at the end).

Note that uniqueness in the output depends on uniqueness in the input (`file1`). That is, if field 2 in the input is repeated, this code won't notice. There is also nothing that can be done with the current design even if a duplicate was spotted; the old row has been printed so printing the new row will simply cause the duplicate. If you were worried about this, you could design the `awk` script to keep the whole of `file1` in memory and only print anything when the whole of the input has been processed. Needless to say, this uses a lot more memory than the current design, and will generally be less efficient because of that. Nevertheless, it could be done if needed.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.. That was quick by you and easy.. also could you please explain on the second if condition..? Second "if" is started with "{".. is this second loop on a file after first if condition?

Comment: There are three blocks. The first is the `FNR == NR` block; it processes the first file processed aka `file2` (because that's when the file record number matches the overall record number, and because the `next` skips the rest of the processing for the given line). The next block is the one you're referring to (I think); it applies to each line in the second file. It looks to see whether the record number is known, and if it is and the date for the replacement is more recent than the date in the file (`file1`), then it prints the revision; either way, it removes the record for cleanliness.

Comment: If the record is not in the `file2` data, then the record is simply printed.  The third block is the `END` block. It looks for any records still left in the `line` array and prints them; they were not matched by anything in `file1` so they must be added.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can start your `awk` as follows:

```
awk -f script.awk input2.csv input1.csv > result.csv
```

you can use the following script to obtain the desired output:

```
BEGIN  {
    FS = OFS = "," 
}
FILENAME == "input2.csv" {
    date[$2] = $3
    data[$2] = $0
    used[$2] = 0
}
FILENAME == "input1.csv" {
    if ($2 in date) {
        used[$2] = 1
        if ($3 < date[$2])
            print data[$2]
        else
            print $0
    }  else {
        print $0
    }
}
END {
    for (key in used) {
        if (used[key] == 0)
            print data[key]
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The script takes advantages of the assumption that file2 is smaller than file1 because it uses an array only for the few entries in file2.
- The new entries are simply appended to the output. There is no sorting. If this is required there will have to be an extra effort.

**EDIT**

Heeding @JonathanLeffler's remark about the way I determine which file is being processed I would like to offer an alternate version that may (or may not :-) ) be a little more straight forward to understand than checking `NR=FNR`. However, it only works for sufficiently recent versions of `awk` which are capable of returning the size of an array as `length(array)`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}
{
    # The following effectively creates an array entry for each filename found (for "known" filenames existing entries are overwritten).
    files[FILENAME] = 1
    # check the number of files we have so far
    if (length(files) == 1) {
        # we are still in the first file
        date[$2] = $3
        data[$2] = $0
        used[$2] = 0
    } else {
        # we are in the second file (or any other following file)
        if ($2 in date) {
            used[$2] = 1
            if ($3 < date[$2])
                print data[$2]
            else
                print $0
        }  else {
            print $0
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (key in used) {
        if (used[key] == 0)
            print data[key]
    }
}
```

Also, if you require your output to be sorted according to the second row you can replace the call to `awk` by this:

```
awk -f script.awk input2.csv input1.csv | sort -t "," -n -k 2  > result.csv
```

The latter, of course, works for both versions of the script.

Comment: The basic logic looks sound and very similar to what I used (I delete used entries from the array; you have the auxilliary array `used` to convey the same information). However, by keying on the two file names, you render your code very brittle, whereas my code would work with `input2.csv` and `input1.csv` as well as it does with `file2` and `file1`. In some ways, the `FNR == NR` idiom is not so pleasing, but it does work well for treating the first file differently from the others.

Comment: Thanks Marcus.. your solution worked well too as Jonathan.. :) you rock